# Where can I find a reputable agent to help me with a patent?

Tags: patent-agent

I was wondering where I can find a reputable person to assist with a patent. Whenever I go online, I end up with a lot of junk mail and annoying phone calls. How do I find someone to help guide me in the direction achieving a patent without my information being passed or sold to solicitors?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the places you are responding to online are invention submission companies. Both the [USPTO](http://patents.uspto.gov/inventors/scam_prevention/index.jsp) and the [Federal Trade Commission](http://www.consumer.ftc.gov/articles/0184-invention-promotion-firms) have information warning about the practices of many firms in that industry. You will also see inventors on-line who have got their own patent through the system and are now holding themselves out as qualified to help other inventors. The only people who have been blessed by the USPTO to do this are "registered patent practitioners". The complete list is at [https://oedci.uspto.gov/OEDCI/](http://oedci.uspto.gov/OEDCI/). You could search that list by city or zip code and find someone nearby.  Or you could use that list the net time you see something on-line that looks interesting to se if the person is registered.

Answer (score 0):

You could search for USPTO registered patent agents at https://oedci.uspto.gov/OEDCI/.
If you sign NDA (Non-disclosure Agreement) with the agent, then the agent would be bound by contract, and would not pass your information to anyone.

Comment: That same database lists patent attorneys and patent agents. As part of getting listed, they all took an oath to the Federal goverment to put their client's interests ahead of their own interests, including not disclosing their confidential information.